# How can I make parent-child relationships work?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a website of engineering and construction in which I have list of products such as bridge, towers and all are linked. When the user clicks on bridge then its type appears from mysql table on the same page which is in the form of image but the problem is again I want to retrieve the value i.e. its sub-types which are also images. And then when user clicks that image its details will be appeared. Basically its a hierarchy up to 3-4 levels. But don't know how to make relationships between tables.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: show a few more examples of your hierarchy to make it easy and pertinent to do an answer.. Is it like bridge:suspension, bridge:arch; arch:metal,arch:wood... what is your tree of relations like?

Comment: First you should try to find those punctuation marks you appear to have lost...

Answer (score 0):

If the items in your hierarchy can be generalized enough, you could make a single table with the columns: id, parent, information

One entry could be id=Bridge, Parent=Architecture, information=picture_source

You can then make lookups like, show me every entry that has Architecture as its parent and send the list to the client.

Comment: There are two divs oh the left sides list of prodducts like Bridges,Towers when the users click on bridge then in the rt div type of bridge appears in the form of image lets say bailey bridge when the users click bailey brides again I want to show types of bailey bridges which we hav completed in different location in the form image again when it is clicked its details will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use `InnoDB` engine for mysql. `MyISAM` don't support foreign keys (if you are using the default).

you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: "MyISAM don't support relationships" ?!? WTF ?!?

Comment: @arkascha, but how do you define relationships in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use **parent -child relationships** like this,
**example:**

1. when clicked on bridge - take data from child 1 table having same fk-key from main table ,
   so your all bridge types will appear
2. Do same for all your sub items